# Command line to compare two file list and delete files that shows on both lists

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command-line-arguments

In windows 7, I have a folder1 that contains below files:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

There is another folder2 that contains below files:

```
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
```

I would like to use command line to delete files `b.txt` and `c.txt` from folder2, which appear in both list.
I understand how to generate a file list using `for /f`. I don't know how to do another loop within the `for /f` so I can delete files.

Comment: Which platform/OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean you want files b.txt and c.txt removed from *both* folders, or just one. The following batch file will remove them from folder2.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set folder1=name_of_your_first_folder
set folder2=name_of_your_second_folder
for %%f in (%folder1%\*) do (
    if exist %folder2%\%%~nxf echo del %folder2%\%%~nxf
)
rem remove echo from above once satisfied it will do the right thing
```

Comment: Don't you need `for /f %%f` to start with?

Comment: No, unless you want to read the contents of a file, or execute a command and read the contents of its output. If you just want to go through the file names in a directory, just use it without any options. Type `for /?` for help.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on you shell and your OS.  If you're using bash then I would think something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

folder1=a
folder2=b

for f in $folder1/*.txt; do
    g=`basename $f`
    if [ -f $folder2/$g ]; then
        echo "remove $folder2/$g"
    else
        echo "not in $folder2 $g"
    fi
done
```

Comment: this is under windows 7 environment, can you provide a solution I could use as .bat/.cmd?

Comment: Sorry ... I don't have access to a Windows box right now.  I shouldn't have assumed bash.

Comment: No worries. Much appreciated if you can look at it when you had a chance.